# latex command has extra space

Tags: spacing

I'm writing a command to deal with bacteria names. They're written in full the first time, then with just the first name and a period following it. I've managed what I have by cobbling together others' examples, though I seem to have an extra space. I'm ignoring for now that sometimes the second name is shortened as well.

MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\def\splitfirstchar#1#2\sentinel{#1.}
\newcommand{\first}[1]{\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel} 

\def\testwords#1{%
    \readwords#1\relax
}
\def\readwords#1 #2\relax{%
    \ifcsundef{bactused}{
        \def\bactused{true}%want full name
        \textit{#1 #2}
    }{
        \textit{\first{#1} #2}
    }
    %\relax
}
\def\ecoli{\testwords{Escherichia coli}}
\begin{document}
\ecoli
\ecoli\ecoli. Blah
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

So where is the extra space coming from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need `%` at the ends of your lines that containt `\textit{...}` and the line that ends with `{`

Comment: Huh. Good to know. I'm still only just beginning to start out with programming in LaTeX. I never understood why everyone stuck `%`s at the end of so many lines which didn't look like they needed it.

Comment: @EricR: A end-of-line character (i.e. a line break) is normally taken as a space. If you add `%` at the end it is commented out. Note that any spaces after a macro is removed, so you don't need to add `%` in such lines. An exception are the single character macros like `\_` etc. which do not delete following spaces.

Comment: I realised the line break was a space I guess I just didn't think about that when writing a command. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 5):

TeX considers a `<return>` as whitespace just like it does a number of consecutive spaces. So, in your instance, there's actually a return after every use of `\ecoli`. The `%` "removes" this `<return>`.

From the [TeX Book](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) regarding the SHORT STORY by A. U. Thor (Chapter **6 Running TeX**, p 26):

> The `%` sign here is a feature of plain TeX that we haven't discussed
>   before: It effectively terminates a line of your input file, without
>   introducing the blank space that TeX ordinarily inserts when moving to
>   the next line of input. Furthermore, TeX ignores everything that you
>   type following a `%`, up to the end of that line in the file; you can
>   therefore put comments into your manuscript, knowing that the comments
>   are for your eyes only.